# Export Grouped rows of datatable in Excel file

Tags: jquery, asp.net, excel, datatables, export

In JQuery datatable, I cannot export the grouped rows using button exports. I have done column row grouping code for grouping rows in data tables and when i exported the table using "buttons" the grouped rows are not exported.

When I export it shows only actual table data without grouping header.
How can I export my table data with grouping header along in excel format?

Comment: Ever solve this problem?